# Xcode XCtest Cannot find executable for CFBundle

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have added the XCTest in my existing Xcode project. And then just try to Test(cmd+U) it. The test is failed and console prints below message. My Xcode version is 5.0.2 and iOS 7.0.

Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xd738670  (not loaded)
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-esndmcenxdzinffpdzbakmpbztpl/Build/Products/Development-iphonesimulator/***.xctest'
Program ended with exit code: 0

Any help/suggestions is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by delete test target, delete(remove references) test folder, add new test target, add  files to new test folder.

Happy fixing.